# Reaction in a order discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i want to add a message with reactions but i want reaction to have certain order. The problem is when i execute command to add that message, the reactions add randomly.

Code:

```js
        case "helptest":
 indexTest = 0;
 comandUser = message.author.username;
 message.channel.send(mesajeTest[indexTest]).then(function (message) {
  message.react("⏪")
  message.react("▶")
  message.react("◀")
  message.react("⏩")
 });
 break;
```

I want that order which is in code to be in reactions message, any solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved the problem with async function

```js
  case "helptest":
 indexTest = 0;
 comandUser = message.author.username;
 message.channel.send(mesajeTest[indexTest]).then(async function (message) {
  await message.react("⏪")
  await message.react("◀")
  await message.react("▶")
  await message.react("⏩")
 });
 break;
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does your send function return? A Promise of what? Maybe multiple Promises get resolved before the callback of the first one is finished.

Did you try using [Promise.each()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html)?

> With *Promise.each()* Iteration happens serially. If the iterator function returns a promise or a thenable, then the result of the promise is awaited before continuing with next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As OP states, the accepted answer works for this specific case, however i just ran into a similar problem, however my emoji:s are generated, so typing them out on a line isn't an option. So i naturally tried to look over them all and await each in time. However node seems to smart for this and optimized the code to run in parallel instead of sequentially. I ended up having to fold all the promises into a single promise using reduce like this:

```
[...array of emojis...].reduce((promise, emoji) => promise.then(() => message.react(emoji)), Promise.resolve());
```

Even though there's an accepted answer I'm going to leave this answer here in hopes that others might find it helpful.